# ServiceNow Google Map widget

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, widget, servicenow

I'm trying to create a ServiceNow Google Maps widget that shows the logged in user's location.  I have a server script that simply pulls the user's location:

```
data.location =gs.getUser().getLocation()
```

and my html is as follows:

```
<div class="map-container">
    <iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?key=xxxxxxxxxx={{data.location}}" allowfullscreen/>
</div>
```

This renders the generic world map from Google, but does not specifically display the user's location.  I've tried using ng-src instead of src, but that actually renders nothing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you look at the source on the element and see if it appears correct for the `src`?

Comment: Hi Kirk, when i inspect the element, the src is rendering correctly in <iframe>

Comment: @Dave: are you doing this in Service Portal? Can you shoe the generated URL?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could take a look an this out-of-the-box widget "ticket-location".
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/helsinki-servicenow-platform/page/build/service-portal/concept/ticket-location-widget.html

There are some useful snipptes which you could use for your widget, like map options:

```
var mapOptions = {
  scrollwheel: false,
  zoom : 17,
  center : $scope.latlng,
  mapTypeControl : true,
  navigationControlOptions : {
    style : google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
  },
  mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```